# to get the real type information of a pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class myclass1 {
public:
    virtual ~myclass1() {

    }
};

class myclass2 : public myclass1 {

};

int main() {

    myclass1 obj1;
    myclass2 obj2;

    myclass1 *p1 = &obj2;
    myclass2 *p2 = static_cast<myclass2 *>(&obj1);

    if( p1 && p2){
        cout << typeid(p1).name() << endl;
        cout << typeid(p2).name() << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is as below:

```
P8myclass1
P8myclass2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image: cion capture]

The code has two classes, I tried to use two types pointer to point to the other type. From base class to its children is totally ok while the other way around should not work ("myclass2 *p2 = static_cast<myclass2 *>(&obj1);"). If I use "dynamic_cast", the casted pointer will be null. But if I use "static_cast", the cast seems successful and the type is "myclass2" when I use typeid method.

When I am in debug mode in Clion, it seems the debugger knows the  real  type of the pointer, as shown in the image. It knows the type of p1 is "myclass2" and type of p2 is "myclass1". What is the magic of it?

```
obj1 = {myclass1} 
obj2 = {myclass2} 
p1 = {myclass2 * | 0x7ffeec114a08} 0x00007ffeec114a08
p2 = {myclass1 * | 0x7ffeec114a10} 0x00007ffeec114a10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeid(p1)` will give you the type of the pointer `p1`, which will always be `myclass1 *` (the string `P8myclass1` is the mangled name for the type `myclass1 *`).  If you want the type of the pointed-at object, you want `typeid(*p1)`, which should be `myclass2` in this case.

With p2, `typeid(p2)` will be `myclass2 *`, while `typeid(*p2)` gives undefined behavior -- you can't safely dereference a pointer after a static cast to the wrong type.  It is *likely* that you'll get `myclass1`, but not certain -- you might get a crash.

The debugger is essentially doing that with extra knowledge and protection to avoid bad misbehavior from the undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. typeid(*p2)  gives me p1 in this case But do you means this result is not always  like this? Basically I just want to do a safe type check before doing cast, or at least I know I did the wrong cast.  It seems by dynamic_cast I can achieve this by checking if the returned pointer is NULL. But there is no such mechanism for static_cast? So I should always prefer dynamic_case over static one?

Comment: Correct -- dereferencing the pointer after an incorrect static_cast gives undefined behavior, so you can't rely on what you get -- so you should never use static_cast unless it is known to be safe.  dynamic_cast exists to make safe casts like this.

Answer (score 1):

The "magic" is likely undefined behaviour. You can't `static_cast` a pointer to point to a different type except in specific situations (like an upcast). In your case, `&obj1` points to a `myclass1` object, not a `myclass2` object, so it is completely meaningless to perform the downcast.

Comment: You can (safely) static_cast -- you just can't do anything with the resulting pointer other than static_casting it back to the original type.